# Identify Wifi networks uniquely while scanning

Tags: java, android, arraylist, wifimanager

I want to add Wifi scanning functionality to my app which will scan all the wifi networks within the range and list the SSID in a Spinner. I have managed to implement this using the following code. But when scanning it shows multiple network names with the same name(there are no same networks when scanning with wifi settings of the phone)and many blank lines in the Spinner. I appreciate any suggestions on how I can prevent this issue by uniquely identifying the network names without duplicating or blank lines.

Please find my Wifi receiver class here.

```
class WifiReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    WifiManager wifiManager;
    Spinner wifiDeviceList;
    String[] deviceList;
public WifiReceiver(WifiManager wifiManager, Spinner wifiDeviceList) {
    this.wifiManager = wifiManager;
    this.wifiDeviceList = wifiDeviceList;
}


public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();
    if (WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION.equals(action)) {
        List<ScanResult> wifiList = wifiManager.getScanResults();
        deviceList = new String[wifiList.size()];

        for (int i = 0; i < wifiList.size(); i++) {
            deviceList[i] = ((wifiList.get(i).SSID));
        }


ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, deviceList);

        arrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        wifiDeviceList.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From API level 24 (Android 7.0) onward sorted by the strongest networks first:

```
List<ScanResult> wifiList = wifiManager.getScanResults();
List<String> ssids = wifiList.stream()
    .sorted((sr1, sr2) -> sr1.compareTo(sr2)) 
    .map(scanResult -> scanResult.SSID)
    .filter(ssid -> ssid.equals(""))
    .distinct()
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. but for some reason .sort and level(ScanResult::level) does not exist. Would you be able to explain your answer little bit.

Comment: It was a mistake on my part. It's fixed now

Comment: I checked on the above fix also(I have added condition to run above code for api 24 onwards ). But Im still getting lot of empty lines and repeated networks.